# What areas of SharePoint call the Role Provider Methods?

Tags: role-provider, membership-provider

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975135%28v=office.12%29.aspx#MOSSFBAPart2_MinimumInterfaces) on MSDN about the minimal methods required for Role Providers on SharePoint.

My question is about the other methods in the Role Provider (GetUsersInRole, IsUserInRole, FindUsersInRole, etc.).  Are any of these methods called from within SharePoint or are they only used by custom code that would call these?

If they are called from within SharePoint, where are they called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since i created a custom role provider, but i think those commands are called from within some of the people picker controls.

If you have a custom role provider you can just set a break point inside the method implementation and see.